# Erase some lines of file in the range defined by keywords with Python

Tags: python-3.x

How do I filter a section of text between two strings in Python?

For example, I would like to filter out all lines between `CLUSTERED BY` and `BUCKETS` in the following text:

```
    CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
CLUSTERED BY (fv,
              sv,
              tv) 
SORTED BY (fv,
           sv,
           tv) INTO 2 BUCKETS;
-- more text afterwards
```

The result should be:

```
    CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
-- more text afterwards
```

Comment: Hi Vadim and welcome to SO. To help you out with this question, it would be good to know what you've tried and a little more about what you're trying to achieve. For example: Have you got as far as loading the file into a `string`? Do you need help with writing the result back out to a new file? Are you trying to modify the file in-place?

Comment: Hi, @jelford. I try to modify any SQL file with Python script. Now I want to receive part of code that read any SQL or TXT file and check it for blocks like CLUSTERED...BUCKETS. When script check this block, script should remove this block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
start_word = "CLUSTERED"
end_word = "BUCKETS"

result_lines = []

with open(target_file, 'r') as f:
    erasing = False
    for line in f:
        if not erasing and start_word in line:
            // begin erasing lines
            erasing = True
            continue

        if erasing and end_word in line:
            // finished erasing lines
            erasing = False
            continue

        if erasing:
            // we are between the start and end of the section we want to erase
            continue
        else:
            // either we haven't started erasing or we have already finished
            result_lines.append(line)

print('\n'.join(result_lines))
```